# Анимирование цвета

Tags: spritekit, objective-c, xcode, ios7

Как можно анимировать переход из цвета A в цвет B в SKShapeNode?

Comment: Меняй цвет в UIView aninateWithDuration

Comment: Если я пытаюсь в Sprite Kit вот так поменять цвет фона:
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];}];
То смена без анимации.

Comment: Еще вариант - customActionWithDuration:block:

Comment: Как им пользоваться?

Comment: мануал [customActionWithDuration][1]


  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:

Answer (score 1):

Интерполировать

```
@implementation UIColor (Interpolation)

+ (UIColor *)interpolateColorFromStartColor:(UIColor *)startColor endColor:(UIColor *)endColor position:(CGFloat)position {
    const CGFloat *startComponent = CGColorGetComponents(startColor.CGColor);
    const CGFloat *endComponent = CGColorGetComponents(endColor.CGColor);
    float startAlpha = CGColorGetAlpha(startColor.CGColor);
    float endAlpha = CGColorGetAlpha(endColor.CGColor);

    float r = startComponent[0] + (endComponent[0] - startComponent[0]) * position;
    float g = startComponent[1] + (endComponent[1] - startComponent[1]) * position;
    float b = startComponent[2] + (endComponent[2] - startComponent[2]) * position;
    float a = startAlpha + (endAlpha - startAlpha) * position;

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a];
}

@end
```

position от 0 до 1

```
SKAction *colorAction = [SKAction customActionWithDuration:3 actionBlock:^(SKNode *node, CGFloat elapsedTime) {
    ((SKShapeNode *)node).fillColor = [UIColor interpolateColorFromStartColor:[UIColor redColor] endColor:[UIColor blueColor] position:elapsedTime/3];
}];

[shapeNode runAction:colorAction];
```

Работоспособность экшена на шейпе не проверял.

Comment: И что мне напитать чтобы в течении 3 секунд был переход?

Answer (score 0):

возьмите как вариант 2 пикселя (png в один пиксель) один цвета А, другой цвета В и с помощью Sprite Node и runAction меняйте картинку